# 'Java heap space' error with neo4j -- when increasing memory allocation fails

Tags: neo4j, heap-memory

I have used the import tool to read in ~1 million nodes. Now it is time to set relationships.  (Unfortunately, it looks like you have to have relationships predetermined explicitly in a csv if you want to use the import tool, so that is out of the question.)

First thing I did was to put an index on the nodes.

Next, I wrote this, which I'm wondering is my problem -- even with an index, this statement might cause too many cartesian products?:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///home/monica/...relationship.csv' AS line
MATCH (p1:Player {player_id: line.player1_id}),  (p2:Player {player_id: line.player2_id})
MERGE (p1)-[:VERSUS]-(p2)
```

Apparently the `USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500` didn't help, as I got my error,

```
Java heap space
```

Googling around, I learned that it might help to change my memory settings in the neo4j-wrapper.conf file, so I changed the settings all the way up to 4GB (I have an eight GB system):

```
wrapper.java.initmemory=4096
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096
```

Still got the same error.

Now, I'm stuck. I can't think of any other strategies, besides:

1)  rewrite the statement
2)  use a system with more RAM?
3)  find some other way to run this in batches?

Any advice would be awesome. Thanks to the neo4j SO community in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an index or an unique constraint on `:Player(player_id)` ? if the former, drop the index and add an unique constraint instead. Otherwise it is possible to have multiple Player nodes sharing the same `player_id` - which could cause cartesian products, assume you have 10 times the very same player, this would end up in 100 combinations for each line of your csv.

Once you're sure there is no such duplication the next thing to check is `EagerPipe`. If the query plan (without `PERIODIC COMMIT`)

```
EXPLAIN LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///home/monica/...relationship.csv' AS line
MATCH (b1:Player {player_id: line.player1_id}),  (p2:Player {player_id:     line.player2_id})
MERGE (p1)-[:VERSUS]-(p2)
```

shows something with `eager` then `PERIODIC COMMIT` is not applied, see http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/ for details.

The cases where this could happen gets less and less with a more recent Neo4j version.

## update

I've just realized that you're using `b1` in the match and in the merge a `p1` - so the latter does not exist and gets created as new node during merge.

Can you please try:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///home/monica/...relationship.csv' AS line
MATCH (p1:Player {player_id: line.player1_id})
MATCH (p2:Player {player_id: line.player2_id})
MERGE (p1)-[:VERSUS]-(p2)
```

Comment: I did as you say; I removed the index, added a unique constraint, and then checked the query plan. Indeed...there is an `eager` lurking! Now I need to read the documentation and see how I can work around this. Thanks for pointing me in this direction.

Comment: The link to Mark Needham's blog recommends avoiding doing too much during any one iteration of `LOAD CSV`. In my case, I'm only doing one thing in one iteration of `LOAD CSV`...

Comment: Which neo4j version you're on?

Comment: I am on version 2.3.2

Comment: argh, I am so sorry but my post contained a typo! There should be no 'b'...only 'p'. I retyped it a bit too hastily. My apologies! I'll edit the original post right now. :(

Comment: does the issue vanish if you use two `MATCH`es (see update in my reply) instead of only one with a comma?